# Export OpenStreetMap paths to KML

Tags: openstreetmap, kml, kmz

Is there a way to export OpenStreetMap public transport routes to a KML or KMZ file? I'm trying to view the routes in another application (Google Earth) which supports KML data, but doesn't support the OpenStreetMap API.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please read [how to ask a good question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is too broad as it currently stands.

Answer (score 7):

Check out the [Overpass Turbo API](http://overpass-turbo.eu/).
Use the wizard to simply search for your desired OpenStreetMap routes using their location or the route's osm-id and then press the export-tab. There you can choose "KML" as an export format.

Answer (score 0):

I just searched via Google and found a page entitled [OSM in Google Earth](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_in_Google_Earth) which says:

> Look at [Query-to-map](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Query-to-map) to select small parts or single objects of OSM
>   and show them as KML also in Google Earth.

I recommend reviewing the [Query-to-map](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Query-to-map) page.

Comment: That's probably not what he asked for.